# How do I add pull to refresh in my app with flutter , wordpress?

Tags: ios, json, api, flutter, dart

my app build test app blog with flutter ,back end wordpress  but I don’t know where to add
Can you help?
my app build test app blog with flutter ,back end wordpress  but I don’t know where to add
Can you help?

main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
title: 'blog',
home: HomeScreen(),);}}
```

home.dart

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

List<SinglePost> parsePosts(response) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(response)['posts'].cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<SinglePost>((json) => SinglePost.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

Future<List<SinglePost>> _getPosts() async {
  final response = await http.get(baseUrl);
  return compute(parsePosts, response.body);
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Future<List<SinglePost>> _postsFuture;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _postsFuture = _getPosts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<SinglePost>>(
        future: _postsFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Text("Error"),
              ),
            );
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                elevation: 0,
                title: Text(
                  "blog",
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .title
                      .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
                      child: Image.network(
                        "${snapshot.data[0].avatarURL}",
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              body: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .35,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                    child: PageView.builder(
                      controller: PageController(viewportFraction: .76),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) => OverlayedContainer(
                        authorAvatar: "${snapshot.data[i].avatarURL}",
                        author: "${snapshot.data[i].authorName}",
                        image: "${snapshot.data[i].featuredImage}",
                        title: "${snapshot.data[i].title}",
                        onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                PostScreen(postData: snapshot.data[i]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "All Posts",
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
                        ),
                        ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: 5,
                          itemBuilder: (context, i) => PostContainer(
                            author: "${snapshot.data[i].authorName}",
                            image: "${snapshot.data[i].featuredImage}",
                            title: "${snapshot.data[i].title}",
                            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    PostScreen(postData: snapshot.data[i]),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I don’t know where to add
Can you help?
my app build test app blog with flutter ,back end wordpress  but I don’t know where to add
Can you help?

Answer (score -1):

I know that 
Add in pubsec.yaml
And import package
..
..
but writing the code inside home.dart I don't know